# 2D web-game: on what?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I want to make a basic, 2D fighting game (not fast paced nor does it have many cool effects.)
I could make it with jQuery, but I think that it would run slowly (to my knowledge).

Can anyone give me an alternative to flash for the development of this game?

Comment: What do you dislike about flash, so that we know what to recommend?

Comment: If you target only modern browsers it will run pretty fast. If you must support IE6 and the likes: not good :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like get this game running on the most computers out there I would go for these technologies:

- Flash (fast, and availabable and installed nearly everywhere, frameworks for gameprogramming are out there)
- JavaScript (no browser-plugin required, but performance **will** realy suck, especially at older computers or browsers)
- Silverlight (could be suitable, but still a just a very few people have it installed and I do not know if there any good working versions for Mac and Linux)
- JavaApplets (lesser installations then Flash, could be fine, altough it seems quite unsexy to use JavaApplets in these days.)

Answer (score 8):

You might want to check out [**Processing.js**](http://processingjs.org/exhibition), if you prefer not using browser plug-ins.

Processing.js uses Javascript to draw shapes and manipulate images on the Canvas element. The code is light-weight, simple to learn and makes an ideal tool for visualizing data, creating user-interfaces and developing web-based games.

Comment: Impressive... I thought it wouldn't even be possible.

Comment: Impressive indeed... The only thing that I really dislike about it is performance. It definitely needs work.

Answer (score 3):

I already saw most options listed, but I thought I'd chime in with another great option that is now free (unless your game makes more than $100K/year and then you must pay a one time $1,500 fee: [Unity](http://www.unity3d.com).

This game generation tool allows you to use a visual developement environment with either javascript, boo or C# to develop games that can be played in a browser, on windows or on a mac.  Though it is best known for 3D game development, it certainly supports 2D development.

Here is an example of a [browser based 2D game made using Unity.](http://www.tumbledrop.com/)

Answer (score 2):

[Bubblemark](http://bubblemark.com/) provides a "performance test" of sorts of all of your available options. I'm biased, but I'd still say Flash.

Comment: Thanks for this link, very interesting. For Chrome on my Mac, the DHTML option blew away everything else.

Comment: WebKit in general is incredibly optimized for JavaScript. You'll see radically different results if you try out IE :)

Comment: IE8 for me does about 5fps whereas Safari 4 does nearly 100 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Jquery is not designed whatsoever to do what you want, flash however is the obvious and ubiquitous solution as far as you're talking about a browser game. If you want something localized, look for graphics packages for whatever language you're comfortable with: pygame[python], gosu[ruby]

Answer (score 1):

Saw this yesterday on reddit: http://www.renderengine.com/demos.php JavaScript game engine

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned jQuery for games, and I recently came across [the gameQuery library](http://gamequery.onaluf.org/). Coupled with jQuery 1.4 ([with recent performance improvements](http://ejohn.org/blog/closestarray-in-jquery-14/)) and the fact that all major browser vendors are falling over themselves lately to improve JavaScript performance, building a game without Flash or Silverlight is now feasible and productive.

I have also investigated the Raphaël library (raphaeljs.com), a low-level graphics alternative to Processing.js and canvas mentioned earlier. SVG elements are indeed compatible with jQuery. [Here's an example of a hex grid on Raphaël with jQuery for click events](http://projects.bkendall.biz/raphael/hex_click.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Effect Games](http://www.effectgames.com/).

It is a free to use, online hosted Javascript Game Engine that runs incredibly smooth and supports all major browsers. Don't believe me? Play this [demo](http://www.effectgames.com/effect/games/crystalgalaxy/), or this [one](http://www.effectgames.com/games/absorb/).

Those that say you must use Flash and Javascript is too slow, obviously haven't been paying attention, especially to the newer browser such as Chrome that utilise [compiled javascript](http://code.google.com/p/v8/). Why use Flash, when you can have a cross platform, cross browser game developed using native browser functionality.

You should also check out [Chrome Experiments](http://chromeexperiments.com/) to see just how much current Javascript (and sometimes HTML5) capabliities have improved.

> Effect Games provides free, online
>   tools for building, sharing and
>   playing your own browser based games.
>
> Your games may include sound effects,
>   music, and multiple layers of
>   parallax-scrolling tiles and sprites.
>
> Users can play your games right in
>   their browsers, without needing any
>   new plugins or extensions.  Publish
>   your games on your website or blog,
>   share on social networking sites, and
>   submit them to our featured games
>   section!
>
> Build your games using JavaScript and
>   our custom browser game engine, level
>   editor, and suite of developer tools. 
>   The Effect Engine supports Mac OS X,
>   Windows, Linux and all modern browsers
>   including IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera
>   and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/) is similar to flash, but not flash.

Answer (score 0):

Flash can be done in the traditional sense or in Flex if you want it more of a traditional programming experience. Silverlight is a great flash substitute if you would rather do your programming in .net. Javascript games are possible but difficult to do I think you would save a lot of your time if you did it in flash instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a great option would be to use [SilverSprite](http://silversprite.codeplex.com/). It allows for creating **XNA** games for **Microsoft SilverLight** using the same knowledge base you find for **Windows** and **XBOX 360** (only working for 2D games so far)

Answer (score 0):

Panda3D is a full-blown game engine that can make browser-based executables. I have not tested this functionality myself, but it seems to work pretty well. 
http://www.panda3d.org

check it out, it rocks.

Answer (score 0):

http://gamejs.org

or any of https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines